# Line Break into New Rows w/ Added Numbered Column

Tags: excel, vba, row

I am using a macro to separate line breaks in an existing cell into new rows. I have that part worked out. Now I want to add a column that numbers each of the rows that were separated.

**Single Cell**

All Info

**Old Setup (multiple rows, one column)**

Row 1 Info

Row 2 Info

Row 3 Info

**Desired setup (multiple rows, two columns)**

1 Row 1 Info

2 Row 2 Info

3 Row 3 Info

I want to start the sequence over when the macro begins to break up a new cell.

Here's the code that I'm working with. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub CellSplitter()
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim CText As String
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim L As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim lNumCols As Long
Dim lNumRows As Long

iColumn = 5

Set wksSource = ActiveSheet
Set wksNew = Worksheets.Add

iTargetRow = 0
With wksSource
    lNumCols = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    lNumRows = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For J = 1 To lNumRows
        CText = .Cells(J, iColumn).Value
        Temp = Split(CText, Chr(10))
        For K = 0 To UBound(Temp)
            iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
            For L = 1 To lNumCols
                If L <> iColumn Then
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = .Cells(J, L)
                Else
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = Temp(K)
                End If
            Next L
        Next K
    Next J
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim vLine As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim lSplitCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsData = .ActiveSheet
        Set wsDest = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    lSplitCol = 5

    aData = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To UBound(aData, 2) + 1)

    ResultIndex = 0
    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        lCount = 0
        For Each vLine In Split(aData(i, lSplitCol), Chr(10))
            lCount = lCount + 1
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            aResults(ResultIndex, 1) = lCount
            For j = LBound(aData, 2) To UBound(aData, 2)
                If j = lSplitCol Then
                    aResults(ResultIndex, j + 1) = vLine
                Else
                    aResults(ResultIndex, j + 1) = aData(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
            If ResultIndex = UBound(aResults, 1) Then
                wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults
                ReDim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To UBound(aData, 2) + 1)
                ResultIndex = 0
            End If
        Next vLine
    Next i

    If ResultIndex > 0 Then wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults
    wsDest.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete xlUp

End Sub
```